# Do I need a question mark at end of statement ending in a parenthetical question?

Tags: questions, em-dashes

If a sentence ends with a question offset by an em-dash does it end with a period or a question mark? This is the example:

> Lucy scans for forgotten manglow mentions, but the margin notes contain only her data for resolving Mangifera humboldtensis’ central question— how did a subtropical angiosperm survive cold damp Humboldt County?

Comment: I would be tempted to use something like ... "central question:  How did a subtropical angiosperm survive cold damp Humboldt County?"

Comment: With that phrasing, I would include the question mark. If you feel awkward about the question mark, you could rephrase it so that one isn't needed: "… central question — how a subtropical angiosperm survived cold damp Humboldt County."

Comment: And sort that spacing around the dash.

Comment: @ralph.m thanks! That solution really works for me. Thanks Stuart F for callout on spacing!

Answer (score 0):

The direct question at the end of the sentence licenses a question mark. Even if you thought that the first part of the sentence (a statement) justified a period at the end, the question mark would override it. The Chicago Manual of Style says:

> When more than one mark of punctuation (excepting quotation marks, parentheses, brackets, and sometimes dashes) is called for at one location in a sentence, only the stronger or more necessary mark is retained. (CMOS 14th ed., section 5.135)

It then gives two examples, the second of them demonstrating that "the period . . . is omitted in deference to the question mark". This suggests that a question mark is "stronger" than a period and is the mark that is retained.

Note that although this answer cites only CMOS, I'm fairly confident (based on experience) that most major style guides would recommend including a question mark (rather than a period) at the end of your example sentence.

By the way, I agree with Hot Licks (in a comment above) that a colon would work better than a dash here. Capitalizing the following letter is optional.

Comment: What are the two examples given in CMOS? (I can't find this entry in my edition.)

Comment: @TinfoilHat 1) "Have you read the platform?" asked Mark. 2) What had she meant when she said, "The foot now wears a different shoe"?